# Pasar un String obtenido de una base de datos al src de una imagen

Tags: php, html

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de pasar un dato `String` obtenido de una base de datos para referenciar una imagen, aquí el ejemplo:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src='img/menudia/paletamango.png' alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <h3><?php printf("%s", $NAME); ?></h3>
          <p><?php printf("%s", $DESCR); ?></p>
          <P> $<?php printf("%d", $COSTO); ?></P>
          <P> <?php printf("%s", $IMG); ?></P>


          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="post.html">Ordenar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Necesito que el texto `String` de la variable `"$IMG`" esté como referencia para la imagen en lugar de `"paletamango.png"`

O sea sería algo como `src='img/menudia/(Aquí iría la información de $IMG)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes concatenarlo del siguiente modo:

```
<?php echo "<img class='img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0' src='img/menudia/".$IMG."' alt=''>" ?>
```

Así sería la línea completa de `<img>`

Comment: Me funcionó a la perfección! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Cómo bien comenta el compañero, puedes concatenarlo, sin embargo lo ideal sería poner una **imagen default** en dado caso de que al registrar el articulo, esta información no se tenga a la mano. utilizando un `if()` junto con un `isset()` puede comprobar si dicha variable está definida, en dado caso que no, pondrá la imagen por defecto.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <a href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid rounded mb-3 mb-md-0" src='img/menudia/<?php if(isset($IMG)){ echo ($IMG); } else { echo("sinimagen.png"); ?>' alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h3><?php printf("%s", $NAME); ?></h3>
      <p><?php printf("%s", $DESCR); ?></p>
      <P> $<?php printf("%d", $COSTO); ?></P>
      <P> <?php printf("%s", $IMG); ?></P>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="post.html">Ordenar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ahora bien hay que recordar que PHP lee el documento de inicio a fin, por lo que deberás declarar la variable antes de ejecutar la condicional `if()`, cosa que asumo debido a que no la estás declarando en ningún momento.
Así también, te recomiendo que almacenes en la base de datos el nombre completo del archivo de la imagen junto con la extensión, para evitar tener que concatenar la extensión.
Espero te funcione :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder! El otro método me funcionó bien por ahora y me es un poco más fácil de comprender, pero voy a tomar mucho en cuenta lo que usted me dijo para reforzar

Comment: Si, a lo que me refiero es que con este código puedes **hacer una validación** (con la condicional `if()`) para comprobar que la variable `$IMG` está definida (utilizando la función `isset()` que comprueba si está definida la variable que se pasa por parámetro), por ejemplo que en la base de datos esté guardado como "paletadefresa.png", si es así imprimir el resultado de la consulta; **PERO** si no está definida, el sistema automáticamente mostrará una imagen como "Imagen de paleta no disponible", dándole un diseño más profesional y evitando ver un espacio vacío en la página.